# Difference in a bare and non-bare Git repository

Tags: git

In git, I was just wondering what the difference between a bare and a non-bare repository are. I know that a bare repository is typically just pushed to and changes aren't made within it. Other than that, what makes it different than a repository that is non-bare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bare repository has just the .git folder without a checked out source tree.
Bare repository is usually used in the remote depository.

Non-bare repository has both .git folder and source tree.