# push changes in git not reflecting

Tags: git

I am very new to git and I am facing the following issue.
I have set up a remote server and local server and I am trying to push changes from the local server into the remote server. 
The push works fine without any errors but the changes/files that were pushed from the local server are nowhere to be seen in the remote server.

What am I missing.?

EDIT: 
The steps I am following are as follows:

In the remote server, I initialise the git in a test folder as follows

```
git init --bare
```

In the local server, inside a test folder with a few files I do the following steps

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git add origin user@remote_server_ip:/path_to_test_git_folder/
git push origin master
```

following this I get the below message, which leads me to believe the push is successful

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 279 bytes | 279.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To 10.0.8.54:srv/git/test.git
   97f4e97..30429fb  HEAD -> master
```

But the files/changes inside the local server does not show up anywhere on the remote server.

Comment: Could you explain how are you doing this: commands and steps? To find out what's missing, we need to figure out the current steps.

Comment: Are you checking the correct branch on your remote?

Comment: @F.Igor I have added the steps I am following currently

Comment: @kowsky I believe I am looking at the correct folder. I even ran a machine wide search to see if the files are turning up elsewhere.

Comment: @AshSharma A branch is not the same thing as a directory.

Comment: Why did you create a bare repo on the server? What you're describing sounds like a bare repository working as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in a bare and non-bare Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833791/difference-in-a-bare-and-non-bare-git-repository)

Comment: @melpomene I was following an online example to setup git repositories. Thank you for the valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the files/changes inside the local server does not show up anywhere on the remote server.

Which is expected, considering a bare repo does not have by definition a working tree.

You would need a post-receive hook in order to force a checkout somewhere on your server for the file to show up, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838994/6309).

```
/path/to/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/bash
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/workingtree git checkout -f  -- .
```